Grammar of Pausal Forms in Selichos, Hoshanos, etc
In the S'lichos of Nusach Lita we read towards the end a tefila, which is stated using the ךָ-ֶ (-ekha) pausal form:

עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן אֲמִתֶּךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן בְּרִיתֶךָ. עֲשֵׁה לְמַֽעַן גָּדְלֶךָ וְתִפְאַרְתֶּךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן דָּתֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן הוֹדֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן וִעוּדֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן זִכְרֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן חַסְדֶּךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַעַן טוּבֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן יִחוּדֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן כְּבוֹדֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן לִמּוּדֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן מַלְכוּתֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן נִצְחֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן סוֹדֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן עֻזֶּךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן פְּאֵרֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן צִדְקָתֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן קְדֻשָּׁתֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן רַחֲמֶֽיךָ הָרַבִּים. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן שְׁכִינָתֶךָ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן תְּהִלָּתֶךָ.

In the Yom Kippur Nussach Ashkenaz, the same tefilah is stated in the
ךְ-ָ (-akh) pausal form:

עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן אֲמִתָּךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן בְּרִיתָךְ. עֲשֵׁה לְמַֽעַן גָּדְלָךְ וְתִפְאַרְתָּךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן דָּתָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן הוֹדָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן וִעוּדָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן זִכְרָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן חַסְדָּךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַעַן טוּבָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן יִחוּדָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן כְּבוֹדָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן לִמּוּדָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן מַלְכוּתָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן נִצְחָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן סוֹדָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן עֻזָּךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן פְּאֵרָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן צִדְקָתָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן קְדֻשָּׁתָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן רַחֲמֶֽיךָ הָרַבִּים. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן שְׁכִינָתָךְ. עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן תְּהִלָּתָךְ.

By comparison, on Succos we say all the Hoshanos in the later form. What is the origin of these differences and what is the correct way to say?
I also saw a similar difference between some siddurim in pointing the piyut Y'did Nefesh (Seuda Shlishi of Shabbos). What is interesting, is that everybody sings the melody as if it was written for the -akh form but incorrectly pronounces the nekudos of the printed -ekha form, especially the first line. The same problem is with the last stanza of Dror Yikra (thanks Double AA).

It's not whether female or male, but whether using a pausal form or not. See Moses I. 14:21 for example.

Interestingly, in the Chabad slichos it is written אֲמִתֶּךָ etc., but a footnote states that the Rebbe would say אֲמִתָּךְ etc.

Female suffix would end with -eikh not -akh

The short answer is all these texts used to all be in the -akh form in accordance with rabbinic Hebrew standards. Later some people changed some to -ekha thinking that was more right, but the change was only accepted sporadically and inconsistently across prayers and editions.

@DoubleAA there is an answer that deals with this, isn't there? That's a nice summary - I'd like to see it. possible dupe?

@DoubleAA If we accept it as a Rabbinic pausal form, then the gender may become ambiguous. I saw some discussion of this here in the context of the MT but not the siddur. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38106/why-is-%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%9A-in-genesis-2440-pointed-%D7%90%D6%B4%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9A%D6%B0-rather-than-%D7%90%D6%B4%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%9A%D6%B8

@Kazibácsi either way it is a pausal form then. Non-pausal would be ךָ-ְ

As @DoubleAA also pointed out, the second person singular feminine possessive suffix is ךְ-ֵ. The ambiguity comes when we're talking about the conjugated forms of the -ל prefix, as it is like in Esther 5:6. But there are many grammatical ambiguities in the Tanakh.

another good example is the last stanza of dror yikra. when you revert back to the original form the meter suddenly matches the other stanzas

@DoubleAA How so? I see quantitative meter of 3-3 full vowels per line everywhere, but the last paragraph will be 3-2 if you use ־ָךְ endings. Qualitatively, the meter isn't consistent even before the last paragraph.

@magicker72 Double AA is counting stressed syllables, it is a dimeter iamb if each printed line is actually 2 lines and we counting shva na as a vowel. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)

@YDJ Still doesn't work with stressed syllables — באף ועברה doesn't work, אלהים תן (or אלהי תן) doesn't work, ונרחיב פה doesn't work, ישע and ונמלאנה are מלעיל, and לשוננו is מלרע, etc. Not to mention that דעה חכמה לנפשָךְ doesn't break into iambs.

Hm I honestly don't remember what I meant, but I'm pretty sure I saw this listed as an example of historical corruption of this form. Don't have the time to dig into spanish meter terms now.
